# Set option value in a select field

Tags: forms

The array generated gets me the information that I need, but it's created a keyed array where the key is numeric (0..length-1).  How do I change it so that key is equal to the value, so that the option value is equal to what is displayed?

```
$page = $sql->execute();
$pages = array();

    // Populate page dropdown
    foreach($page as $p)
    {
      $pages[] = $p->title;
    }
// Display only unique values in the array
$paged = array_unique($pages);

// Sort the array in ASC Order
sort($paged);

$form['group_owner_filter']['select'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Filter by Name'),
    '#default_value' => t('Make a selection...'),
    '#options' => $option
  );
```

This generates:

```
<select id="edit-pages" name="pages" class="form-select">
    <option value="0">About Davenport</option>
    <option value="1">Academic Support Center</option>
    <option value="2">Academics</option>
    <option value="3">Adjunct Insurance Scholar Opportunity</option>
    <option value="4">Admissions</option>
```

Comment: First problem I can see if that `'#options' => $option` should probably be `'#options' => $paged`

Comment: @Queenvictoria would probably be right. You can simply replace **$pages[]** with **$pages[$p->title]**, inside for loop. You can also skip its next step involving array_unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the corrected code. I've changed some variable names to make it easier to understand.

- `$option` and `$pages` became `options`
- `$page` became `$pages`
- `$paged` was retired

As @Sujith-Nara mentions you don't need `array_unique` as the keyed approach will make them unique by default. This does presume that the page titles are unique across the site (which is *not* enforced). You could replace the key with `$p->nid` or `$p-name` if the titles aren't unique.

Because the keys are now strings you can use `ksort` instead of `sort` to order them on the key.

```
$pages = $sql->execute();
$options = array();

// Populate page dropdown
foreach($pages as $p)
{
    $options[$p->title] = $p->title;
    // $options[$p->name] = $p->title;
    // $options[$p->nid] = $p->title;
}

// Sort the array alphabetically in ASC Order
ksort($paged);

$form['group_owner_filter']['select'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Filter by Name'),
    '#default_value' => t('Make a selection...'),
    '#options' => $options
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`drupal_map_assoc()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/drupal_map_assoc) function to convert a linear array into an asscoiative array.

```
$pages = drupal_map_assoc($pages);
```

> Forms an associative array from a linear array.
>
> This function walks through the provided array and constructs an associative array out of it. The keys of the resulting array will be the values of the input array. The values will be the same as the keys unless a function is specified, in which case the output of the function is used for the values instead.